# webdav tomcat configuration

Tags: tomcat, ms-word, ms-office, webdav

I want to open files which are in serverside and edit and save there itslef

ex : `http://localhost:8080/WEBDAVTESTDEMO/myDocument.doc`

I'have configured webdav in tomcat mentioned [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/WebdavServlet.html) .

I'm able to open the file and able to edit aswell(I'm sure the document is not opened in read-only mode).

The problem is when I try to save ,I'm getting the strange error . See below

"There has been a network or file permission error. The network connection may be lost."

Is there anybody who faced this issue?

How to resolve this issue??

[image]

Comment: Are you able to browse thoses directories with the Windows Explorer. I do know that Microsoft' WebDAV client is quite crappy. I had my problems with that too.

Comment: Yes I can able to browse files and able to open

Comment: Are able to open a textfile and save it?

Comment: The text file is directly opening in web browser :(

Comment: No, open the directory in Windows Explorer, right click and open with your favorite text editor.

Comment: I tried but still the txt file in opened in IE automatically.
It is not prompt me to "choose a program to open";

Answer (score 0):

Webdav protocol usage in MS Office has been changing rapidly over recent years, and its necessary for webdav servers to continue being developed to maintain compatibility. I'm not sure how active the tomcat servlet is, and whether its been keeping up.

My webdav server project is a bit more complex then the tomcat webdav servlet, but is actively maintained with full compatibility for all major webdav clients - http://milton.io